# Handle process signals in Swoole script without pcntl_signal() function

Tags: php, daemon, pcntl, swoole

I'm implementing a php parallel tasks script based on Swoole module which works as daemon.

Is it possible to use Swoole functions to handle process signals instead of pcntl_signal()?

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
declare(ticks=1);

use Swoole\Coroutine as Co;

$stopCommand = false;

$sigHandler = static function (int $sig) use (&$stopCommand)
{
    switch ($sig) {
        case SIGTERM:
            $stopCommand = true;
            break;
    }
};

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, $sigHandler);


Co\run(function() use (&$stopCommand) {

    $results = [];
    while(true) {

        //go(static function () use (&$results, &$stopCommand) {}

        co::sleep(1);

        if(!$results && $stopCommand) {
            break;
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Swoole Process Signal](https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-process-signal)

[Main-page to Swoole Process](https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-process)

Please also explore Swoole Process Manager, and binding process with Swoole Server using addServer(), and Swoole Process Daemon.